# When to use withContext(NonCancellable) versus WorkManager to run code after app is killed/backgrounded?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have a simple and fast operation such as inserting an important log into an on-disk database. This needs to be guaranteed even if the user closes the app (we don't want to lose the log), and so my initial hunch was to use `WorkManager` to guarantee that this task runs and inserts it into the database.

However, upon learning about the NonCancellable coroutine context, I'm wondering if `withContext(NonCancellable)` is better. Since adding a single event to a database is a very fast operation, I'm wondering if using `WorkManager`is overkill here - the API documentation says WorkManager should be used for long-running, persistent work (like making network requests, etc)

What are the situations in which `withContext(NonCancellable)` is appropriate to be used over `WorkManager`, outside of code that handles cleanup?

Comment: IMHO, `withContext(NonCancellable)` is pretty much exclusively for `finally` blocks (or perhaps a `catch`) where you need to invoke a coroutine and are not in position to handle cancellation. If your concern is that you are using `viewModelScope` for your disk writes... then do not use `viewModelScope` for disk writes!  Instead, create your own process-level `CoroutineScope` that you use for that sort of I/O. See [this repository](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/-/blob/master/T34-Work/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/ToDoRepository.kt) for an example.

Comment: @CommonsWare appreciate your comment! There is the risk of the process being killed / getting backgrounded / crashing while handling the disk write though, and in that case, even a process-level CoroutineScope would not end up logging the event though, right?

(I understand this is a small concern but just want to be clear on my thinking here)

Comment: "There is the risk of the process being killed / getting backgrounded / crashing" -- the UI moving to the background is not a problem, though the other two are. "in that case, even a process-level CoroutineScope would not end up logging the event though, right?" -- yes, but `withContext(NonCancellable)` does not help with that either.